# offline mobile website

Tags: mobile, web

Is it possible to have a mobile website that can still function if there's no internet connection?

The user should still be able to use the website (if he has visited that page before), see the data (that was loaded before), add new stuff (cache locally).
When internet connection comes back online, all changed local data should be pushed online.

This should be a complete webbased solution, not a native app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have a look at HTML5 offline storage, see http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/offline.html and the [Offline Web Applications spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/offline-webapps/) as a start. There are also quite a few posts here on SO.

Comment: interesting links. I will investigate this further. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Bookmarklets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) work when a user is offline. The trick with a bookmarklet is that it's entirely self contained javascript wrapped up in such a way that it can live within the bookmark itself. E.g. a `javacsript:` URL. You can also have a [`data:` URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) as a bookmark, which could be a complete HTML page. Usually these are base64 encoded with a mime type.

Probably what I'd do would be have a small base page as `data:text/html,base64` which contained whatever offline content you cared about, but periodically tried to bootstrap the rest of the "real" content from wherever you host it.

Comment: I don't understand how this could work (my knowledge is not good enough). Could you elaborate more on this. Thanks

Comment: Basically you design the page you want. (As a single HTML page usually) You then base64 encode the file and append it to data: text I showed in the answer, e.g. <a href="data:text/html,base64,PCEF....">. From there all you need to do is get that URL added as a bookmark. That bookmark will work regardless of if the user is offline.